# how start frame animations in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to start 5 different `frame animations`:One for cap,one for scarf
one for character,one fro face Expressions and one for scarf borders.I want it to look like man is running with scarf hat.Animations started fine,
but all animations are not playing at same time.
Please help me to do that.

I set the png images through addFrame method in  my code .

#### I am posting the sample code here

```
   capanimation.setVisible(true,true);
    capanimation.start();
    Log.i("fani"," cap:  "+System.currentTimeMillis() );
    scarfmainanimaiton.setVisible(true,true);
    scarfmainanimaiton.start();
    Log.i("fani"," sca:  "+System.currentTimeMillis() );
    
    faceexpressionanimation.setVisible(true,true);
    faceexpressionanimation.start();
    Log.i("fani"," fac:  "+System.currentTimeMillis() );
    
    charecteranimation.setVisible(true,true);
    charecteranimation.start();
    Log.i("fani"," cha:  "+System.currentTimeMillis() );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this using frame by frame animation which is very easy. I will provide link for that check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation.html
In that you can put your images in resources folder and that can animated as per requirement. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi pavan thanks for your quick response,i did same like both in xml and in Code by using addFrame method. Also 5 animations are playing well but all 5 animations are not synchronized

Comment: I think you take images differently means these are not sequential. Is these images are cut from gif image?

Comment: Yes, pavan all are the sequential and are cut from the gif images. and alos i checked manully in xml for each images there is  no problem in images. same images are used in Iphone there it is working fine

Comment: Why you are starting different animation instead you can start it from single animation. Can you show some more code?

Comment: In may app i am giving choice to user to select cap,scarf among different options
      based on the user selection i need to animate that cahrecter with user selcted cap and scarf
  charecteranimation=new AnimationDrawable();
     scarfmainanimaiton=new AnimationDrawable();
    // etc...
  for(int i=0;i<maledance.length;i++)
  {
   charecteranimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(maledance[i]),100);
  capanimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(maledancecap[i]),100);
  scarfmainanimaiton.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(maledancescarf[i]),100);
    }

Comment: Then change your xml file on user selection and  set using follwoing method  images.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demo_animation); That is you have to make xml files' having different combination. Then check respective at run time and give to setBackground method.

Comment: i treid in the code as well as with the combination of xml files but none of them worked for me finally i achieved that by using runnable thread instead of frame animation. for each reptetion of thread i set different images for the image views

Comment: i dont know it is possible or not in android through frame animation. if u think it is possible i will send the images and my code please help me to do that.and one more thing is, it is working fine in emulator but in my htc wild fire this animation is not so looking good(not sychronize all animations)

Answer (score 0):

In may app i am giving choice to user to select cap,scarf among different options
         based on the user selection i need to animate that cahrecter with user selcted cap and scarf

```
     //Iam posting the some sample code here
     public  int maledance[]={R.drawable.char01,R.drawable.char02,R.drawable.char03,R.drawable.char04,R.drawable.char05,R.drawable.char06
                ,R.drawable.char07,R.drawable.char08,R.drawable.char09,R.drawable.char10,R.drawable.char11,R.drawable.char12,R.drawable.char13,R.drawable.char14,R.drawable.char15};

    public int maledancescarf1[]={R.drawable.scarve101,R.drawable.scarve102,R.drawable.scarve103,R.drawable.scarve104,R.drawable.scarve105,R.drawable.scarve106,
            R.drawable.scarve107,R.drawable.scarve108,R.drawable.scarve109,R.drawable.scarve110,R.drawable.scarve111,R.drawable.scarve112,R.drawable.scarve113,R.drawable.scarve114,R.drawable.scarve115};
```

etc......

```
       charecteranimation=new AnimationDrawable();
        capanimation=new AnimationDrawable();
        capboarderanimation=new AnimationDrawable();
        scarfmainanimaiton=new AnimationDrawable();
        scarfboarderanimation=new AnimationDrawable();
        faceexpressionanimation=new AnimationDrawable();
        for(int i=0;i<maledance.length;i++)
        {
            Log.i("fani","string lenth is  "+maledance.length+" delay is "+delay);
        charecteranimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(maledance[i]),t);
        capanimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(maledancecap[i]),t);
        scarfmainanimaiton.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(maledancescarf[i]),t);
        faceexpressionanimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(malefaceexpression[i]),t);
        }
        capanimation.setOneShot(false);
        charecteranimation.setOneShot(false);
        scarfmainanimaiton.setOneShot(false);
        faceexpressionanimation.setOneShot(false);


        //in onwindowfocuschanged listner i am starting the animations
```